# A ListBoxItem that fills its parent

Tags: layout, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a Windows Phone app.

I have the following XAML:

```
<!--ContentPanel -->
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox x:Name="SinglesGameList" Margin="0">
        <ListBoxItem Margin="10,10,10,5" Height="67" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="444">
            <TextBlock Text="XXX"/>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Instead of setting ListBoxItem Width="444" I'm wondering it there is another way to set it that fills its parent.

Any advice?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  
Making things bigger than they need to be has performance issues you need to consider.

Comment: You can set the width of `ListBoxItem` to `Auto`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
<ListBox x:Name="yourListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>                    
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">                       
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>                    
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I've also found this one: http://dandesousa.com/2010/08/29/windows-phone-7-listbox-item-horizontal-width-stretch/