# How can I make a ListBox expand to fit the entire available width?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

[image]

I need to make the ListBox expand to fit the width it has available. Here's the XAML:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2" Height="400" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Notes}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="90" Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="30" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="15" />
                        <Rectangle Fill="#1192D4" Height="2" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [A ListBoxItem that fills its parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639466/a-listboxitem-that-fills-its-parent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at this post
[A ListBoxItem that fills its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639466/a-listboxitem-that-fills-its-parent/5643088#5643088)